# Problem with installation

Tags: system-installation

I have problem with a installation elementary OS. When I choose a installation of the main first I see a message

```
ACPI PPC Probe failed
```

after this I see that

[image].

I tried nomodeset. How  can I install elementary OS? The same  problem I have with linux mint.

Comment: Which graphics card do you have?

Comment: Radeon HD7870XT